# Python generator objects: where are they stopped?

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

I've got tricky questions. This should be interesting, too.

There is a way to know where (source file and line number) a generator object is stopped on the yield statement, waiting to resume execution? Consider also the possibility a generator is delegating to another generator through an 'yield from' statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always grab the `f_lineno` attribute of the frame of the generator object.

Each generator holds a reference to its execution frame in `genobj.gi_frame`. You can peek and find the line number from there:

```
genobj.gi_frame.f_lineno
```

Similarly, if a generator yields from another generator, it has an attribute `genobj.gi_yieldfrom` that contains the other generator object. If `gi_yieldfrom` is not `None` (meaning it does yield from another generator), peek in it's `gi_frame` and get it's line number in a similar fashion.

Comment: SORRY BUT FOR SOME REASON I'M UNABLE TO FORMAT THIS POST - Thank you for your precious suggestion. This is my solution:

    def generator_position(gen_obj):

    if gen_obj.gi_frame is None:
        return '*terminated*'

    elif gen_obj.gi_yieldfrom:
        return generator_position(gen_obj.gi_yieldfrom)

    else:
        return '{}:{}'.format(
            gen_obj.gi_frame.f_code.co_filename,
            gen_obj.gi_frame.f_lineno
        )